# Setting contentEncoding for azure blob streams in node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, character-encoding, azure-blob-storage

So I have a text file with `ISO-8859-1` encoding stored in an azure blob, which I need to process line by line using a stream, since the files can be rather huge.

I have ensured that contentEncoding for the uploaded blob is correct and tried various settings like `ISO-8859-1`, latin1, binary, ...

I can download the infile to disk like this and the encoding of the downloaded file is restored locally just fine:

```
const stream = require('stream');
const storage = require('azure-storage');
const blobService = storage.createBlobService();
const containerName = 'myContainer';
const file = 'in.txt';

let readable = blobService.createReadStream(containerName, file, {encoding: 'latin1'});

let outstream = fs.createWriteStream('./out.txt');
readable.pipe(outstream);
```

What I actually want to do instead of downloading the file to disk, is work through the stream with `readline`, parsing the file as the data comes in:

```
const stream = require('stream');
const storage = require('azure-storage');
const blobService = storage.createBlobService();
const containerName = 'myContainer';
const file = 'in.txt';

let readable = blobService.createReadStream(containerName, file, {encoding: 'latin1'});
readable.setEncoding('latin1');
let rl = readline.createInterface(readable);

rl.on('line', function(line) {
    console.log('line: ' + line);
});

rl.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Stream closed.');
});
```

Above code will not work but return an error:

```
TypeError: readable.setEncoding is not a function
```

When I leave out the `setEncoding`, the stream will be processed by readline just fine but the encoding is not correct.

I also tried azure's `getBlobText` (although this is really not what I want), which will fail to verify the `contentMD5` and return an error for files containing latin characters:

```
Error: Hash mismatch (integrity check failed), Expected value is jd2+sYDibe5GCw5JwpMhpg==, retrieved q/IlYBBNY6XluFzKKPq7hw==.
at BlobService._validateLengthAndMD5
```

How do I get out of this without downloading the file to disk?